# Opening a kml file with Google Earth at a specific placemark

Tags: kml, google-earth-pro

I have a local kml file full of Placemarks.

I would like to be able to do the following with one click of a hyperlink in a locally hosted HTML file.

1. Open Google Earth (if not already open)
2. Load this kml file
3. Center on a specific placemark

Just like opening an HTML document to a reference.
I've gone through the KML specifications, but can't see anything that looks like it would help.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To jump to a particular view (e.g. center on a particular placemark), create a [LookAt](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#lookat) or [Camera](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#camera) view on the root-level Document element in the KML.  The top-level view will be used as the default view when the KML is loaded.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
 <LookAt>
 </LookAt>
 ...
 </Document>
</kml>
```